# wondering use of computed property

Tags: swift, properties

before.

```
class DrawingView: UIView {

    var arcCenter = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)  // error
}
```

after.

```
class DrawingView: UIView {

    var arcCenter: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    }
}
```

I know why that error occur, but I can't understand why the second codes are not makes error.

Answer (score 0):

The first form is **not** a computed property.

It is a **stored** property with a default value.

it uses `self` which causes the error because at the moment the default value is going to be assigned the instance is not guaranteed to be instantiated.

An alternative to a computed property – which is *computed* only at the moment it's called – is a lazy instantiated property.

```
lazy var arcCenter: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
```

Unlike the **stored** property the default value is assigned when the property is accessed the first time.

Comment: no need to use a closure. `lazy var arcCenter: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)`